# Flutter Android Google Sign-in error: ApiException: 10 after confirming package name, SHA-1 fingerprints, and setting up consent page

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am trying to use Google Sign-in in my Flutter app, but I am receiving the following error message, even after waiting 24 hours after adding my SHA-1 fingerprint to the Google Play Console (*Im not using firebase*), confirming the package name, adding both debug and release SHA-1 fingerprints, and setting up the consent page:

`PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)`

Additional information:

1. I am using the latest version of the Google Play services SDK.
2. I have tried clearing my app's data and cache.
3. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling my app.
4. I have tried running the app in release mode.
5. I have tried testing the app on a different device.

Expected behavior:

I should be able to sign in with Google Sign-in without receiving any errors.

Actual behavior:

I am receiving the error message
`PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null).`

Steps to reproduce:

- Add your SHA-1 fingerprint to the Google Play Console.
- Wait 24 hours.
- Confirm that the package name in your Flutter app is identical to the
  package name in the Google Play Console.
- Add both the debug and release SHA-1 fingerprints to the Google Play
  Console. Set up the consent page.
- Try to use Google Sign-in in your Flutter app.

Expected result:

You should be able to sign in with Google Sign-in without receiving any errors.

Actual result:

You will receive the error message `PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)`.

**Update**

- the web sign in works fine.
- mobile sign works fine when I use firebase Auth sdk instead of `google_sign_in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue while debugging and trying to fix my issue I delete the google OAuth credentials and create new ones and I was using the old client id inside google sign in package

my two advices are

- wait for some time after creating your OAuth credentials
- do not use clint id for the fits time you test the sign in functionality or make sure it's the same for the current platform and the current SHA1